# Set the required field based on particular conditions

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to indicate a property is a required field without using data annotation attributes?
Instead of using annotation attributes, I want to set it as a required field, based on particular conditions.
For eg, something like below

```
if (true)
{
    //set myObj.Name as required field
}
```

Edit: The reason why I need to do is, I'm calling a business service class of our own framework, which I can not touch, and inside the class, when the entity is being saved, mandatory checking is already catered. 
But, in my requirement, I need to save my entity several times and , each times, the mandatory checking may be different . That's the reason why I need to mark the properties required fields dynamically. 
Otherwise,  I have to made my own mandatory checking before calling the business service class, which I don't want to do.

Comment: May be you can use the getter of that property to throw an appropriate exception if the property is null (or has a default value) or (you could show a pop up too)

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it seems like you need to provide your "own mandatory checking". I say this for two reasons;

- To provide your user meaningful feedback as to why something field is required
- Also, to satisfy the contract of your business service class

Can you have a "validate" method that simply runs through your set of rules (that mandatory checking, that you mentioned earlier) and have it return a list of strings indicating the rules that were violated on an attempt to save. Then you can use these strings to populate the text of a message box, logfile or whatever to provide meaningful feedback to the user as to why something wasn't saved, and also ensuring that data that is saved, is compliant to your business service class.

Comment: Everything you mentioned like providing meaningful feedback..etc have already been done in the business service class, and that's the reason why I don't want to repeat that .

Comment: You state in your question that in your "...requirement, I need to save my entity several times and , each times, the mandatory checking may be different". If you found that for a given save, one of your mandatory checks failed, who do you report that to? You say you want to "indicate" that a field is required. I simply interpreted that as being that you were going to provide feedback to someone.

Comment: When the mandatory checking fail in the business service class, a custom exception will be thrown, and this is how I can know which fields are empty and provide feedback accordingly. And since everything is already there, I just don't want a mess by doing the same thing outside of the business class, if possible.